# How do I use this inside setup script vue js composition api

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I use **Vuexy Admin Template**

Inside it is a file that auto import  all libraries called **auto-imports.d.ts**

However, I can't use the libraries called inside the component

Like the **i18n** library

As shown in the image, all methods are not working with Cannot find name '$t' error

```
<script setup lang="ts">
console.log( t('users.all') )
console.log( $t('users.all') )
console.log( this.$t('users.all') )
</script>
```

The solution I am currently using is an unacceptable solution, but it works, which is to repeat the import inside the setup script

As shown in the image

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
const { t } = useI18n()
console.log( t('users.all') )
</script>
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors " unacceptable solution" - this is the acceptable solution and this is how it's supposed to be used. The lack of imports results in using globals, and globals are generally bad.

Comment: @EstusFlask
Regarding your comment about the question containing images

The reply link contains the reason and is perfect, "Thank you so much. You gave great advice."

I will amend the question immediately when using my pc

Comment: @EstusFlask As for your answer to my question, "This solution is acceptable", how is it acceptable when I am import something that has already been import using the
 auto-imports
that you mentioned in the question
The library is already running inside the template tag
without repeating the import locally

Comment: Generally not for this purpose only How can I use this inside setup script

Comment: I mean this is how composition api is expected to work, the clarity at the expense of extra code. A template operates on internal component instance that may have $t, while there's no such instance in setup. Generally `const t` can be written with ide template and two key presses, and auto imports make it unnecessary to write an import yourself. Generally what you ask about is handled by Unplugin, this results in less imports at the expense of more exotic setup that you may have problems with.

Comment: Notice that i18n has one but it doesn't support this, https://github.com/intlify/bundle-tools/blob/main/packages/unplugin-vue-i18n/README.md#i18n-custom-block . useI18n accepts extra options that you couldn't make use of if `t` was imported automagically

Comment: Please don't provide code as image.

Comment: Please how us the template